# Poor man's inline comments: Should we suggest using these?

Tags: discussion

It just occurred to me that the [markup test](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/7/90) I had done could look better:

**Original**

```
# Finds sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 from 0 to 999 

def find_multiples():
    global numbers

    for i in range(0,1000):
       if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
           numbers.append(i);

numbers = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_multiples()
    print sum(numbers)
```

---

**Inline review**

No-nonsense pure text comments, could use `///` as line starter for many languages.

```
# Finds...
###-^ Put this in a docstring

def find_multiples():
    """Finds sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 from 0 to 999 """
###-^ This allows you to "from x import find_multiples,  help(find_multiples)"
    numbers = []
###-^ Avoid globals
    for i in xrange(0,1000):
###-^ Use xrange if Python 2.x
       if not (i % 3) or not (i % 5):
###-^ Add spaces around operators, simplify
###-^ the boolean/numeric checks
           numbers.append(i);  


###-^ Removed

def main():
###-^ Allows calling main many times, e.g. for benchmarking
    numbers = find_multiples()
    print sum(numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Poor man's inline comments**

Now with muted or louder comments!

```
# Finds...
```

-^ Put this in a docstring

```
def find_multiples():
    """Finds sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 from 0 to 999 """
```

#### -^ This allows you to "from x import find_multiples,  help(find_multiples)"

```
    numbers = []
```

-^ Avoid globals

```
    for i in xrange(0,1000):
```

-^ Use xrange if Python 2.x

```
       if not (i % 3) or not (i % 5):
```

-^ Add spaces around operators, simplify

-^ the boolean/numeric checks

```
           numbers.append(i);
```

-^ Removed

```
def main():
```

-^ Allows calling main many times, e.g. for benchmarking

```
    numbers = find_multiples()
    print sum(numbers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Blockquoted inline comments**

Looks OK, but is very fragile and hates long lines:

> ```
> # Finds...
> ```
>
> -^ Put this in a docstring
>
> ```
> def find_multiples():
>     """Finds sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 from 0 to 999 """
> ```
>
> -^ This allows you to "from x import find_multiples,  help(find_multiples)"
>
> ```
>     numbers = []
> ```
>
> -^ Avoid globals
>
> ```
>     for i in xrange(0,1000):
> ```
>
> -^ Use xrange if Python 2.x
>
> ```
>        if not (i % 3) or not (i % 5):
> ```
>
> -^ Add spaces around operators, simplify
>   -^ the boolean/numeric checks
>
> ```
>            numbers.append(i);
> ```
>
> -^ Removed
>
> ```
> def main():
> ```
>
> -^ Allows calling main many times, e.g. for benchmarking
>
> ```
>     numbers = find_multiples()
>     print sum(numbers)
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     main()
> ```

---

Is the poor man's style an improvement for inline comments? Should we cite it as an option in the FAQ?

Answer (score 5):

Just from my point of view i like the **Inline review** better as it doesn't hurt the syntax highlighting that much and especially **It's easier copy/pasteable**.

When improving on some small pieces of code i'd like to be able to cp for a syntax for functionality check, edit, and put it back. So i really like the idea of using language dependend comments. (even so ### should work great for many languages and sets a good standard)

Comment: +1 I prefer the inline as well