# How to choose a correct answer in Code Review?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which answer to accept?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/which-answer-to-accept)

Just discovered Code Review and I think it's great.

I posted my first question and got two answers full of great advice.

What advice do you have for choosing a correct one?  I will probably use advice contained in both.

Comment: I agree.  Mine's a duplicate.  I really did search for such a post before posting and didn't find.