# How long can code be?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, code-length, character-limit

First of all before, I hate the typical "codez plz" homework question.

I hope this has nothing to do with that, but it is actually a class assignment.

I won't post my code until it is completely working as expected and is understandable.  I also went through the FAQ and felt identified with this:

- Code correctness
- Best practices and design pattern usage in your code
- <strike>Application UI</strike>
- <strike>Security issues in a code snippet, etc.</strike>
- <strike>The performance of your code</strike>

But what I'm still not sure about is how long my code can be.  My project is between 200-300 LOC, and I would never post something like that in SO.  But here it might make more sense, since you don't have to go line by line in detail, rather coding style etc.

I've read through [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-appropriate-length-of-a-code-review-question) and the accepted answer is open.

Mine is a simple-to-understand app, nothing crazy: a straightforward text-based game in Python.

Also, I can't really use any code you propose in my project, so, is it a valid request NOT to post any code, rather an explanation on what's wrong?

Of course this doesn't mean any code, just not actual fixes/improvement.  Is this clear?

My questions:

- Is there a "magic number" of LOC for a simple project that is working, given that I want a "superficial" / coding style review?
- Is it a valid request not to post code?

Should I just post the code and see?

Comment: Note that the character/byte limit for posts on code review is about 65 thousand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a "magic number" of LOC for a simple project that is working, given that I want a "superficial" / coding style review?

We don't enforce any maximum length for code samples. The only rule is that all the relevant code should be contained in the question directly (as opposed to posted on a pastebin for example).

If you post excessively long code samples, it might happen that no one bothers to read through all the code and you get no answers, but you wouldn't be violating any rules. If the code is simple and well-document that helps of course. It also helps if you direct the reader to certain areas of the code that you think are in special need of review.

> Is it a valid request not to post code?

I don't see why not.

Comment: Thank for the reply, I'll post my code as well commented as possible and will try to emphasize I what aspects are the ones I care about for review. Thanks again!