# Tackling overwhelmingly long questions

Tags: discussion, code-length

I'm wondering how some users handle huge amounts of code. There's a [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) question out there right now that I would really like to review. However, as stated in the question - it's 1400 lines.

I know that doesn't make it a bad question, or off-topic or bad code, and I'm not complaining about it.

But sometimes I see giant blocks of code in the tag I troll and I feel overwhelmed just looking at it. Maybe it's because I don't troll a *real language*, but it's near impossible to debug or even compile a lot of VBA questions without reconstructing the workbook layout, module layout, generating data of the correct type - just to avoid errors in trying to *see what it does*.

How is this handled in some of the other tags? Is there an acceptable way of asking a user to break it apart or provide sample data?

---

Possibly related meta posts:

- [What is the appropriate length of a Code Review question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60/what-is-the-appropriate-length-of-a-code-review-question/)
- [How long can code be?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/how-long-can-code-be)
- [Answering Guidelines (answer length)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/answering-guidelines-answer-length)
- [Jack of All Trades, Master of None - Let's work together to offer ultimately better content, faster](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none-lets-work-together-to-offer-ultimately-bet)

Comment: To prevent it as being flagged a duplicate, I *am* concerned the site-culture has changed since the other questions were asked.

Comment: One thing that strikes me with that particular one, is how hard it is to tell where a procedure starts and where it ends, because module-scope variables use the `Dim` keyword instead of `Private`, and because OP doesn't seem to indent the body of their procedures - these would be valid review points.

Comment: You can always write an overwhelmingly long code review.

Comment: [Helpful meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/jack-of-all-trades-master-of-none-lets-work-together-to-offer-ultimately-bet).

Comment: @SirPython thanks, added it to the post

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't troll the tag anymore because I got tired of writing enough to fill a blog post and only getting 20 LoC into the Q. It can be exhausting, particularly when it's usually the same advice over and over again. Take a break, only answer the truly interesting questions maybe.

Comment: @RubberDuck yeah I'm starting to feel the same way, it's just low-hanging fruit, but it's useful to the askers. Unfortunately I don't feel I can help much in other languages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no requirement for a Code Review answer to critique every part of the code exhaustively.  If a question contains a lot of code, some possible responses might be:

- **Ask for clarification in a comment.**  If the question is just a huge code dump with no context, I think it might be fair to suggest that the author improve the question.  (In general, I think that presenting too much code is better than presenting an excerpt that is too short to tell what is going on — up to a certain reasonable point.)
- **State your overall impression.**  Does it seem well architected?  Can you, as a stranger, understand how the code generally fits together?  Is this the right algorithm to use?  If an interviewee presented this code, would you hire him or her?
- **Pick a few functions to focus on.**  If a few lines of code stand out as being problematic, dissect that portion of the program.

Answer (score 7):

What @200_success said.

For the particular post in question, I just started at the top, started critiquing the Naming and, well, never even got past the first `Sub` before I'd already filled a whole post.

That's generally how I tackle those kinds of questions. Start at the start, critique as I go and stop once I've filled a post/run out of time.

Answer (score 5):

You can always ask a user in a comment to improve the question. I often suggest question askers to read [Simon's guide for asking a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562), which contain many tips for making a question easier to review and more attractive for reviewers.

Generally, I feel that the longer the code is, the more context and description there should be in the question. If there's very little context and description given, I downvote and add a comment suggesting the asker to improve their question, and move on.