# My code with a small set of classes may be too much

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, code-length

I have a small set of classes that form an events system that I would very much like opinions on, but they're made up of a few classes that together amount to around 1kloc. I'm a little worried that this might be considered a little too much.  How much code is considered acceptable when posting a question here?

Comment: There is a technical limitation of 30K characters in a question. Note that large code dumps tend to generate high-level reviews. Small code blocks tend to generate in-depth, technical reviews.