# Migrating to Software Engineering - v2

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

Inspired by [this off-topic question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/45208/34757) as an example, this is a follow-up question to [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1311/34757).

If it's true that that we won't (can but won't) ask for another close reason, should we modify this answer ...

> Questions **asking for code to be written** to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review.

... to make it recommend that the OP ask their question on Programmers.SE including:

- A hyperlink to Software Engineering
- A brief explanation (if some questions are off-topic at Software Engineering) of what is an on-topic question at Software Engineering

---

Also [rolfl posted a succinct explanation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14452265#14452265) of the difference between Programmers, SO, and CR, which deserves to be more widely published (perhaps in the on-topic Help of all three sites):

- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - I have **no source code**: I don't know how to do it right, how do I do it?
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - I have **broken source code**: I tried to do it right, but it's broken, how do I fix it?
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - I have **finished source code**: now that I've done it, can it be made better?

Comment: See also [Changing wording of the code-to-be-written and working-code off-topic reasons](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1071/34757)

Comment: I love the idea, but I think the Programmers part needs some more clarity. As it is currently worded, it sounds like the short question "How can I make a Java game?" (almost "give me the codez") is on-topic there, but I believe it wouldn't be on-topic for Programmers unless you describe how you have planned it etc... kinda like a "Design review without any code written" (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yes I think one could summarize what's on- and off-topic at Programmers. Perhaps that means looking at Programmer's Meta, and/or inviting their participation in the answer, and/or posting a question "Please summarize what is on- and off-topic?" on their meta. It's because a multi-sentence explanation might be necessary, too long for a close reason, that I thought of putting a link to a meta-topic in the close reason (instead of stuffing the whole explanation into the close reason itself).

Comment: The [new close reasons](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1691/9357) include links to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest:

1. Create a meta-question titled "Code Review, Stack Overflow, or Software Engineering"
2. Make the second part of the OP above an answer to that question; optionally expand/improve it
3. Add a hyperlink to that topic to the custom close reason(s):

   > Questions **asking for code to be written** to solve a specific problem are off-topic here as there is no code to review: please see [Code Review, Stack Overflow, or Software Engineering?](http://example.com), which explains where to post different types of question.

Comment: Having the meta question as a FAQ is (a great idea) worth doing and whether it makes it to be a close reason yet is step 2. I recommend you set up that question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, the very first question on Meta.CodeReview, is [What should our FAQ contain?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-faq-contain).... and, guess what:

### [What belongs here vs what belongs on StackOverflow](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7/31503).